# Currently Using Rocketgate for CC Processing, but it's not showing up on the re-order form

Tags: payment, admin

We are using Rocketgate to process CC's, however, in the admin, for create new order, and the re-order form, none of the payment options are showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Rocketgate specifically, but when creating a payment method, there's a flag that can control whether or not a payment method is available in the admin panel. Could something be amiss here?

See the `$_canUseInternal` flag [on this wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module#adapter_model). It could also be set dynamically, though, as that page notes.